# Run GUI application as part of BuildMaster deploy

Tags: buildmaster

I need to run a GUI application as part of BuildMaster deploy. Currently I added a PowerShell action that launches that application. The problem is the process is started but there is no GUI. I guess it is caused by the fact BuildMaster agent (that executes the PowerShell script) is a Windows Service. Is there any way to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Windows Service cannot launch applications with a GUI (as of Windows Vista / Server 2008 and newer at least), as they run in session 0 and will never be seen by an actual user. You might be able to hack around this by setting the "Interact With Desktop" flag, but that isn't really recommended at this point.

Is it possible to re-architect the application that has to be run into something that doesn't present a GUI and instead accepts command-line arguments?